# Incorrect nanoseconds in redis-cli --intrinsic-latency

Tags: redis

So I run this command:

```
$ redis-cli --intrinsic-latency 100 
... some lines ...

11386032 total runs (avg latency: 8.7827 microseconds / 87826.91 nanoseconds per run).
Worst run took 5064x longer than the average latency.
```

The problem in this report is that 87826.91 nanoseconds **is not equal** to 8.7827 microseconds.
 **The correct answer** is 8782.69 nanoseconds

About versions:

```
$ redis-cli -v      
redis-cli 3.0.5

$ redis-server -v
Redis server v=3.0.5 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-3.6.0 bits=64 build=9e32aff68ca15a3f
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In redis-cli.c there is this code:

```
static void intrinsicLatencyMode(void) {
    .......
    double avg_us = (double)run_time/runs;
    double avg_ns = avg_us * 10e3;
    if (force_cancel_loop || end > test_end) {
        printf("\n%lld total runs "
            "(avg latency: "
            "%.4f microseconds / %.2f nanoseconds per run).\n",
            runs, avg_us, avg_ns);
        printf("Worst run took %.0fx longer than the average latency.\n",
            max_latency / avg_us);
        exit(0);
    }
```

The problem is in the line that converts microseconds to nanoseconds:

```
double avg_ns = avg_us * 10e3;
```

Instead of 10e3 the code should use 1e3:

```
>gdb -q
(gdb) print 10e3
$1 = 10000
(gdb) print 1e3
$2 = 1000
(gdb)
```

Comment: Please submit this fix as a PR to the Redis open source repository at: https://github.com/antirez/redis